# What database table can be best for a container terminal or container yard as a warehouse?

Tags: database-design

I have a warehouse, in fact a container yard. In this warehouse, I store items (in my case, containers or boxes with 2 different sizes, 20 foot and 40 foot).

The containers are not stored on shelves but rather stacked on top of each other.  So a container can be in warehouse A, Block A1, Bay 1, Row 1, and Tier (or level) 1 to 5.

Bay is a section of a block capable of storing Row * Tier (for example 6 row by 5 tiers = maximum 30 boxes). So A1-03-04-03 shows a container in block A1, Bay 03, Row 04, and height or tier 03 (there are 2 containers under this one)

Tables can be:

- Container { container_id, container_number, container_size, ... }
- Yard { yard_id, yard_name, ... }
- Block { block_id, block_name, yard_id... }
- Bay { bay_id, bay_name, max_row, block_id ... }
- Stack { stack_id, bay_id, max_tier,... }
- Container_Stack { container_stack_id, stack_id, container_id (unique, one-To-one relation), entry_time }

Or alternatively can be defined as

- Container { container_id, container_number, container_size, ... }
- Yard { yard_id, yard_name, ... }
- Block_Bay_Stack { block_bay_stack_id, block_number, _number, stack_number }
- Container_Location { container_location_id, block_bay_stack_id, container_id (unique, one-To-one relation), entry_time }

I need to define maximum row and maximum number for stacking containers, also I need to have a flexible schema to store 2 sizes of containers in slots/cells/ ie., one 40’ container is stored in two adjacent 20’ cells. And sometimes 2 20’ containers are stored in the same cells.

Should I define 20’ cell as my smallest cell/bin, or should I define 40’ cell as my smallest storing spot? What schema can you suggest? Thank you!

Comment: We cannot tell anyone what is "best" in an engineering situation unless they define it in enough detail & give enough relevant details that everyone would agree on a valuation. And unfortunately results are chaotically dependent on details. And even if that could be done it's too much for a question here. And you would need to explain where & why you were stuck evaluating that yourself. Such questions are too broad. Although nevertheless often faqs. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Comment: So I can't answer this fully (basically this would be a 2-3 month job to get it right) but I can suggest the following: 1. Don't use `Id`s - these are just row identifiers and will make your life very difficult 2. Composite keys will help keep things in order. 3. You will need a good portion of the logic handled by transactions - for example, not placing placing a container across two rows that aren't adjacent, placing it across two rows at different tiers, etc.  There is no data model that can encompass constraints across multiple entities without transactional validation.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, this can't be answered definitively, but I would suggest reading this [first](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) and then using this as a starting point:

[image]

The first step is just making sure everything is in order.  Then you can start determining keys and how to keep things consistent (i.e. if stacks are identified by they order in the row, determining adjacency is simple).

As you go along and get stuck then your questions might be more specific and better suited to StackOverflow ("How can I ensure an object is stored in adjacent slots",etc).

Comment: Thank @bbaird, to clarify: cell A  and B are  adjacent, each can store a 20' box. if  to store a 40' box it fills both A and B; in database  is it possible to relate the 40' box to cell A and deactivate cell B or refer cell B to A to find it  holds a 40' box?(consider 20' cells as smallest unit, preferred for me) or if 40' cell is defined as base - one to many relationship with contents (a 40' cell can hold one 40' or 2 20' containers)?. Also I  find the tier/level based on the date/time a container is stacked  rather than defining a fixed tier/level as there is no rack in a container yard?

Comment: So it's possible to relate the 40' box to cell A and B through *transactions*.  Basically, you do not let anyone issue their own insert/update/delete statements, instead they have to use a procedure that implements the logic required to maintain integrity.  So if you try to put a container in A + B and one cell is occupied or the wrong type, the insert/updates would not be allowed.  For the tier, you can either use when the container was stacked, a numbering system, or create an optional relation to refer to the cells/containers it is placed upon.